# Результирующая таблица для raw запроса

Tags: sql, django

Есть RAW запрос (код урезан), который находится во view.py

```
class MyUsers(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField('email', max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField('first_name', max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField('last_name', max_length=255)

def internal():
    sqlRequest = '''SELECT <long long select>'''
    myusers = MyUsers.objects.raw(sqlRequest)
```

Код работает.

Вопрос:
Когда выполняется manage.py makemigration создается миграция (несмотря на то что это view.py), которая создает соответствующую таблицу в БД. Эта таблица нужна только для получения результата запроса. Возможно ли ее как-то пометить что эту таблицу не надо создавать в БД, так как она существует только runtime?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#managed

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо